# Anyone know much about drill pumps?

Tags: plumbing, pump

The specs on the ones at Lowes' and HomeDepot's web site were either unavailable, unimpressive, or confusing (e.g. 0.1 horsepower, 0 head pressure, 115 volts, etc.)  I found some available from Northern Tool and Grainger, however, that say they can achieve 50-55 ft of head:

http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200384668_200384668

http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/DAYTON-NonSubmersible-Drill-Driven-Pump-3YU63

http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/DAYTON-NonSubmersible-Drill-Driven-Pump-Kit-3YU62

What I need this for is basically filling up a few systems of copper tubes that range anywhere from 25 to 40 ft in height.  I'm not sure if they'll ever get any taller than 40-50 ft, but I suppose if I ever have to do that, I can just plumb two in series.

Any thoughts on the drill pumps from NT and Grainger?  Suggestions are welcome if anyone knows where to get better drill pumps (or something similar.)

PS: The drill pump will be powered by a [Makita BHP452](http://www.makita.com/en-us/modules/tools/ToolDetails.aspx?ID=24064).

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Just curious.

Comment: are you trying to pump from the bottom of the pipe up, or are you trying to pull the water from the top of the pipe?

Comment: Drill pumps don't prime very far, so I'm pumping from the bottom up.

I went to NT to buy one, but they didn't have the one that was on the web site.  Instead, they had this one ( http://www.walmart.com/ip/Performance-Drill-Pump-W1143/14668087 ), which I purchased.  It's ok, but it takes quite a while to move the 6 gallons that the system holds.  I guess it's really pumping at 3.75 gallons per minute, in accordance to the specs, but still isn't quite what I was hoping for.  I'll probably end up buying one that hooks up to an outlet.

Answer (score 1):

After doing more work with the drill pump, I've decided that it's actually pretty good.  It takes roughly 2 minutes to pump 6 gallons @ 15 ft of head, so I supposed that'll work.  I'll just have to make sure my Makita's battery has a good charge on it before I start pumping.